# How to count number of occurences of each row and display it in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with different downtime causes that can get repeated.

Example:

| downtime | cause |
| --- | --- |
| x1 | A |
| x2 | B |
| x3 | c |
| x4 | A |
| x5 | A |
| x6 | B |

I am trying to work out a way to give the following result, in another table in the same db; but I can't make any code  that I have tried work.

| downtime | cause | occurence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1+x4+x5 | A | 3 |
| x2+x6 | B | 2 |
| x3 | C | 1 |

note: each row has a different id

How can I do this please?

I tried a few methods over the past few weeks, I tried working with the id which I then realized was a mistake ;and it simply did not show the  desired result.

Comment: what is your table? a class  with list of items of this class?  could you show the code you have tried..

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Frenchy my table is a model (public class) with many columns among them (public string? Downtime { get; set; }
        public string? Reason { get; set; }
       )   ; and as for the code i don't remember exactly what i wrote since i am still a beginner and it was some time ago but i made a mess trying to match the ids..

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn SQL server 2022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can [group by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-7.0) the `cause` property and use `Count()` in the select statement to count the occurences:

```
var result = myTable.GroupBy( x => x.cause )
       .Select( s => new myNewType
        {
            downtime = string.Join( "+", s.Select( d => d.downtime)),
            cause = s.Key,
            occurence s.Count()
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If your downtime is some kind of text, then you can do this:

```
create table input(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    downtime nvarchar(32),
    cause nvarchar(1)
);

insert into input(downtime, cause)
values
('x1', 'A'),
('x2', 'B'),
('x3', 'C'),
('x4', 'A'),
('x5', 'A'),
('x6', 'B');

create table output(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    downtime nvarchar(128),
    cause nvarchar(1)
);

insert into output(downtime, cause)
select STRING_AGG(downtime, '+') within group ( order by id), cause
from input
group by cause;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7051a/1

[image]

If `downtime` is numeric and the result needs to be the sum, then the insertion can be changed as follows:

```
insert into output(downtime, cause)
select sum(downtime), cause
from input
group by cause;
```

If you are to use entity framework, which was not specified in the question, then you will need to write your code in such a way that it will generate the logic above. If you do not need a second table, but you only need to select, then you can remove the insert clause and you'll be fine.

Comment: thank u but the issue is with searching the occurences by the "cause" column in the already filled table in order to fill in the new table with the total downtime of that cause andits number of occurences;  and actually yes i am using entity framework ( forgot to mention it, sorry)  and i am a beginner at that ;

Comment: @mariem so, occurrence should be a number? Then use `count(*)` in the query instead of `sum` or `string_agg`. If I misunderstood your question, then please provide a precise description of what you need instead.

Comment: i solved it using linq and by using "TotalDuration = g.Sum(t => int.Parse(t.Downtime))", since my downtime could be a string; thanks again for ur time

Comment: @mariem happy to help and I'm glad your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

try creating a table function which you call from mvc using the following sql

```
SELECT cause, String_Agg(downtime,'+') downtime, count(*) Occurrences FROM table GROUP BY cause
```

Comment: i never used table functions before, i'll search this option some more, thank u

Comment: if you don't use String_Agg than you have to use xpath to collapse rows into a single column by group